# Like Case Sensitive in MySQL

Tags: mysql, case-sensitive, sql-like

I have a MySQL query:

```
SELECT concat_ws(title,description) as concatenated HAVING concatenated LIKE '%SearchTerm%';
```

And my table is encoded utf8_general_ci with MyISAM.

Searches seem to be case sensitive.

I can't figure out how to fix it. What's going wrong and/or how do I fix it?

Comment: the relevant manual page (for 1 version!) http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-sensitivity.html

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT_WS(title,description)) AS concatenated 
WHERE concatenated LIKE '%searchterm%'
```

or (to let you see the difference)

```
SELECT LOWER(CONCAT_WS(title,description)) AS concatenated 
WHERE concatenated LIKE LOWER('%SearchTerm%')
```

Comment: Tried that, still case sensitive.

Comment: @PmcMachinery: did you see that I changed your LIKE part with a lowercase string?

Comment: Yes, thanks, I did. When I do this, I can find uppercase "SearchTerms" too. It doesn't seem that LOWER is doing anything.

Comment: I figured it out. Seems that concat_ws converts the result to a BLOB. Which UPPER and LOWER doesn't work on. I fixed this by adding CONVERT( ... USING utf8) to convert the BLOB to a UTF8 string and then run the LOWER function on that. SELECT LOWER(CONVERT(CONCAT_WS(title,description) USING utf8) AS concatenated 
WHERE concatenated LIKE '%searchterm%'

Answer (score 53):

A much better solution in terms of performance:

```
SELECT .... FROM .... WHERE `concatenated` LIKE BINARY '%SearchTerm%';
```

String comparision is case-sensitive when any of the operands is a binary string.

Another alternative is to use `COLLATE`,

```
SELECT ....
FROM ....
WHERE `concatenated` like '%SearchTerm%' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Comment: I think he wants the searches case INsensitive.

Comment: No BINARY search is case SENSITIVE. BINARY means it is comparing the binary values of each character, rather than the letters they represent. In non-binary comparison "A" = "a", where as in binary comparison "A" != "a" because 65 != 97. You have this backwards. This IS however useful for those that are looking for case-sensitive searches.

Comment: Just tried: `SELECT 'a' LIKE 'A'; -- 1` ; `SELECT 'a' LIKE BINARY 'A'; -- 0`. So binary search is case insensitive. Objections?

Comment: Binary REALLY shouldn't be case insensitive. I suspect there's something wrong with your test case if you're seeing case insensitive results. Though I wouldn't put it past the MySQL devs to do something this depraved, I guess.

Comment: @kolypto Why does your answer say "string comparison is case-sensitive" and the comments here say "binary search is case insensitive"? Binary search is clearly sensitive, as your example shows.

Comment: @Naltharial, :) sure, just confused the terms. Binary strings make comparisons case-sensitive, that's for sure. Sorry

Answer (score 6):

In this method, you do not have to select the searched field:

```
SELECT table.id 
FROM table
WHERE LOWER(table.aTextField) LIKE LOWER('%SearchAnything%')
```

Comment: This answer was first posted almost two years ago... there's no point doing it again.

Answer (score 1):

Check CHARSET mentioned in the table schema:

```
show create table xyz;
```

Based on CHARSET, you can try the following.

```
select name from xyz where name like '%Man%' COLLATE latin1_bin;
select name from xyz where name like '%Man%' COLLATE utf8_bin;
```

Following are the cases which worked for me, CHARSET=latin1, MySQL version = 5.6.

```
mysql> select installsrc from appuser where installsrc IS NOT NULL and installsrc like 'Promo%' collate latin1_bin limit 1;
+-----------------------+
| installsrc            |
+-----------------------+
| PromoBalance_SMS,null |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)

mysql>
mysql> select installsrc from appuser where installsrc IS NOT NULL and installsrc like 'PROMO%' collate latin1_bin limit 1;
+---------------------------+
| installsrc                |
+---------------------------+
| PROMO_SMS_MISSEDCALL,null |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select installsrc from appuser where installsrc IS NOT NULL and installsrc like 'PROMO%' limit 1;
+-----------------------+
| installsrc            |
+-----------------------+
| PromoBalance_SMS,null |
+-----------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for completion, in case it helps:

As stated on https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case-sensitivity.html, for default character sets, nonbinary string comparisons are case insensitive by default.

Therefore, an easy way to perform case-insensitive comparisons is to cast the field to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT type.

Here is an example with a check against a single field:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE CAST(`field1` AS CHAR) LIKE '%needle%';
```

Answer (score -1):

This problem is occurring in this case because of the collation used in the table. You have used `utf8_general_ci` as collation. If the collation is changed to `utf8_general_ci` then the searches will not be case sensitive.
So, one possible solution is to change the collation.

Answer (score -2):

This is the working code:

```
SELECT title,description
FROM (
 SELECT title,description, LOWER(CONCAT_WS(title,description)) AS concatenated
 FROM table1 
) AS Q
WHERE concatenated LIKE LOWER('%search%')
```

Answer (score -2):

This works also:

```
SELECT LOWER(DisplayName) as DN
FROM   Bidders
WHERE  OrgID=45
HAVING DN like "cbbautos%"
LIMIT  10;
```