# MySQL query, don't display record based on name

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table which holds events. Each event has a name, but events are grouped based on their name.

```
+---------------+
| NAME          |
+---------------+
| EVENT 1 CHILD |
| EVENT 1 ADULT |
+---------------+
```

Is a sample row. However, when I query for the events, I only want to show one of the event names.

So essentially I only want EVENT 1 ADULT to be displayed, as the child is linked to it via it's name.

I'm not sure how I would do this purly in MySQL, I know I could perform a query then strip out the events with PHP, but it seems silly to do this if I can do it with MySQL.

Any advice on how to tackle this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does it always end in ADULT?

Comment: What about `WHERE NAME LIKE '%ADULT%'` option?

Comment: And "event 1 child" and "event 1 adult" is the contents of the 'name' col? Then I suggest you change it to 3 seperate cols with 'name', 'number', 'type' or something

Comment: @GeertJaminon the events i want to find will ALWAYS end in " ADULT" (without the quotes).

Comment: Then go with what @DainisAbols wrote ;-)

Comment: @DainisAbols is there a case sensitive version of this? %ADULT% matches both lower and higher at the moment. I want upper case only.

Comment: @dotty Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8083455/mysql-like-case-sensitive) then.

Comment: Thanks @DainisAbols, would you mind making this an answer so I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just read the date where there is only `ADULT` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NAME LIKE '%ADULT%';
```

Or, if it is always at the end:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NAME LIKE '% ADULT';
```

**But**, if you need it case sensitive, try this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE NAME LIKE BINARY '%ADULT%';
```

Comment: +1, given her data restrictions this is the most sensible solution.

Comment: @dotty, lol! my mistake. I just read the name not the profile!

Answer (score 0):

You should change your table structure to include a parent_id column. This will allow you to explicitly link child records to a parent without basing it on the name and then you can easily query for just parent records using:

```
SELECT name FROM events WHERE parent_id IS NULL;
```

EDIT:

If you can't change the data (per your comment) then you're stuck with something like this for finding parents:

```
SELECT name FROM events WHERE name LIKE '%ADULT%';
```

And for finding the child of a given adult:

```
SELECT name FROM events WHERE name LIKE CONCAT('%', TRIM(TRAILING 'ADULT' FROM '$parentName', '%');
```

Note that is a totally untested use of CONCAT with a LIKE so it's just a conjecture that it will work.

Comment: Unfortunately the data is being fed via XML from a shop terminal.

Comment: Yes that is unfortunate. I have edited the answer to reflect more possibilities.