# Whats the MySQL equivalent of this SQLite code?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, glob

```
"SELECT DISTINCT `Name` FROM ( SELECT * FROM `Aliases` WHERE ( `IP` GLOB 'ENTERED_NAME' ) ORDER BY `Datetime` DESC )"
```

Basically trying to get all the names that link to the same IP address as the "ENTERED_NAME".

Is there a MySQL equivalent to "GLOB" ?

Comment: `'IP' = 'ENTERED_NAME'`?  Where `IP` is equal to `ENTERED_NAME`?  That would do it.

Comment: The `LIKE` and `GLOB` operators in SQLite are described here: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html

Answer (score 2):

`GLOB` uses wildcards, eg `GLOB 'Foo*'` to match anything starting with `Foo`. Mysql doesn't support this, but you can convert your string to work with `LIKE` as follows:

```
WHERE IP LIKE BINARY REPLACE('ENTERED_NAME', '*', '%') -- replace * with %
```

Comment: Actually, isn't the difference between `GLOB` and `LIKE` that `GLOB` is case-sensitive ?

Comment: @LMD quite so - I’ve edited the answer to perform a [case sensitive like](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14007477/256196).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name` FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `Aliases` WHERE ( `IP` LIKE '%[entered_name]%' ) ORDER BY `Datetime` DESC
)
```

...or...

```
SELECT DISTINCT `Name` FROM (
    SELECT * FROM `Aliases` WHERE ( `IP` = '[entered_name]' ) ORDER BY `Datetime` DESC
)
```

...where [entered_name] changes accordingly.