# Sort order on matching starting letters in words

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have a table and I’m trying to filter values with “apple m” on `name`

```mysql
select * from table where name like '%apple%m%'
```

```
+-------+-------------------------------+------------------------+
|  id   |             name              |          cat           |
+-------+-------------------------------+------------------------+
|  2757 | Apple MacBook                 | Laptops & Accessories  |
|  2777 | Apple Bottom Tops             | Western Wear           |
|  2752 | Apple Monitors                | Desktop Components     |
|  2756 | Apple Desktop & Monitors      | Desktops & Accessories |
|  2778 | Apple Bottom Tunics           | Tops                   |
|  2776 | Apple Selector & Smart Box    | Video & TV Accessories |
|  2787 | Apple Pie Pyjamas             | Girl Clothes           |
|  2773 | Apple Selector & Smart Box    | TV & Video Accessories |
|  2780 | Apple Fun Card Games          | Toys                   |
| 38304 | Snapple Mixer juicer grinders | Kitchen Appliances     |
+-------+-------------------------------+------------------------+
```

I want to sort display values which start with “apple” and “m” like below:

```
+------+--------------------------+------------------------+
|  id  |           name           |          cat           |
+------+--------------------------+------------------------+
| 2757 | Apple MacBook            | Laptops & Accessories  |
| 2752 | Apple Monitors           | Desktop Components     |
| 2756 | Apple Desktop & Monitors | Desktops & Accessories |
|      | ---Rest all after this-- |                        |
+------+--------------------------+------------------------+
```

Comment: Why do you have `Apple Desktop` after `Apple Monitors`? `D` comes before `M`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
ORDER BY name LIKE 'Apple%m%' DESC, name ASC
```

`name LIKE 'Apple%m%'` is `1` when name matches the pattern, `0` when it doesn't, so this will order the matching names first. Then it will order by the name within each of those groups.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something simple like the following:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE name LIKE 'apple% m%' ORDER BY name;
```

The above query first will get rows with name starting by `'apple '` and then will order the results.

If you need case sensitivity then you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE name LIKE 'Apple% m%' COLLATE utf8_bin ORDER BY name;
```

[Case sensitivity in like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007450/how-do-you-force-mysql-like-be-case-sensitive)

Comment: Hi Kostas, If i do order by on name it will list 'Apple Bottom Tops' & 'Apple Bottom Tunics' first

Comment: Oh, in your expected results you have: Apple Desktop & Monitors so for that reason i thought you wanted that.

Comment: Do you mean than you want only results that one word is 'Apple' and some other word starts with 'm' ?