# Special characters select issues with MySQL

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character-encoding, special-characters, iso-8859-1

Based on http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html I want to perform a search in my MySQL table to see if I have rows that have encoding problems.

If I run the following query :

```
select t.col1 from table t where t.col1 like '%Ãš%'
```

it will bring all the t.col1 that have 'as' characters in them.

How can I change the query to make it fetch **only the rows containing '%Ãš%', and not all that contain '%as%'**.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14007477

Comment: If you want case folding, but accent sensitivity, please file a request at http://bugs.mysql.com .

Answer (score 1):

try this if you are using collation latin1_swedish_ci

```
select t.col1 from table t where t.col1 regexp '^[Ãš]';
```

Comment: Note that `REGEXP` is rather lame -- it does not understand character sets, only bytes.  So Hassan'd use of it happens to work.

Answer (score 0):

With MySQL's collations, case-folding and accent-stripping go together.

If you want neither, use the `..._bin` collation for the character set you are using.

```
WHERE foo LIKE '%Ãš%' COLLATE utf8_bin
```

Even faster would be to declare `foo` to be `COLLATE utf8_bin` instead of whatever you have.  (Note: the default for `utf8` is `utf8_general_ci`.)