# Find UPPER Alphabets in mysql in LIKE clause?

Tags: mysql

I would like to search state_Abbreviation like TX. below is the query I tried so far:

```
SELECT *
FROM `usa_address`
WHERE   ' One American Center, Suite 3000 600 Congress Avenue Austin , TX &nbsp;78701'
             LIKE CONCAT('%',usa_address.city,'%')
    AND ' One American Center, Suite 3000 600 Congress Avenue Austin , TX &nbsp;78701  '
             LIKE CONCAT('%',UPPER(usa_address.state_Abbreviation),'%')
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look good when you're asking for help but can't spend a couple of minutes putting together a readable question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you force mysql LIKE to be case sensitive?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14007450/how-do-you-force-mysql-like-to-be-case-sensitive)